# How i got User Full IP Address like (2405:204:e68c:5415:3599:9ec7:c5c:3f40)

Tags: django

i have create a methord for get user ip address and i use this

this is my view

```
def get_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return HttpResponse(ip)
```

this is my side `http://hp30405.pythonanywhere.com/myip/`

it gives me my ip `47.247.238.18`

but my real ip is

```
2405:204:e68c:5415:3599:9ec7:c5c:3f40
```

how i got this real ip please tell me

and if i use this link in diffrent device then it give same ip in diffrent device it givas ip `47.247.238.18` in all device

Comment: That may be your local IP but it isn’t the IP from which the request comes. If your ISP does NAT in the middle there’s nothing you can do to get the original IP

Comment: but i use it in another device then i give me same ip

Comment: Yes. That’s how home internet NATting usually works

Comment: sir i need to count valid click on my link how i can do that please tell me